# Contouring with background interference

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to get the exterior contour of the object close to the center of the camera.
I'm getting a feed from a **moving** webcam, in this environment (the object is for an example):
[image: Setting]

But when I draw only the center object contour leading to the result such as this:
[image: contours]
(pink circles indicate the center of each contour (light purple). The center object contour is in blue)
As seen above, the meeting point of the floor and the background creates a clear edge passing behind the object, leading to an incorrect contouring.

What would be the approach to get the correct contours (external) in this situations?

**Edit**: Deleted the 2nd part of the question

Comment: Obviously, if you could re-take the image, using a different background will be the best solution..

Comment: if you can't improve image acquisition, AI (magic) is a promising approach. neural networks can give you a segmentation map for whatever objects you care to train them on

Comment: @Guang Thank you for your reply! I could change the wall color/material (black wall consistently resulted in better contours than a white wall) but the floor can't be changed. But I ended up resolving the issue by redesigning the whole system (different light, wall angle etc), so I deleted the 2nd part of the question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your reply! I'm building a sort of inspection system for my printer, so I thought having to train the model whenever the product design changes was not feasible unless the training can be done with very limited amount of training data (i.e., less than a dozen images). Also, if there is a major misprint/defect with the object, I'm worried the object may not even be recognized. But still, I will definitely give it a shot and see if I can use the result to supplement other methods.

Comment: I don't know why people try to monitor and quality-control their print progress with a camera. I think that approach is the opposite of promising.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz For me personally, it was the cost. Also I'm just getting into computer vision so I thought this could be a compact (and somewhat practical) project which requires many different techniques that I need to explore. I'm curious to know what you think is the promising path though, perhaps that could be my next project!

Comment: it's certainly a project that would lead you *all across* the landscape of techniques and mathematics. this touches on 3d reconstruction at the very least, and then you have point clouds or other geometry, and that's another whole world of algorithms. and then, these prints may have texture but that's near impossible to pick up with a camera. it's smooth plastic mostly, so the only visible texture is specular reflection. some kind of monitoring would require AI, and/or some really carefully crafted machine vision techniques (low level, physical, metrology approach).

Comment: Thank you for your insights @ChristophRackwitz. Indeed, I'm planning to use a NN for the texture following a number of studies done on steel surface defect classification. Hopefully I will figure something out about this contouring issue (to locate the object properly) then I'll be able to move towards that step!